# Angular2 Cannot bind to child array

Tags: binding, typescript, angular, ngfor

I have a JSON object like the following:

```
{
  "sessions": [
    {
      "title": Session Title,
      "room": "Ballroom A"
    },
    {
      "title": Session Title #2,
      "room": "Ballroom B"
    }
  ],
  "speakers": [
    {
      "name": John Doe,
      "twitter": "jdoe"
    },
    {
      "name": John Smith,
      "twitter": "jsmith"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to bind to the sessions child of the object.  The full object is in a variable named conferenceData and the code I am using to display the titles is:

```
<div *ngFor="#session of conferenceData.sessions">{{session.title}}</div>
```

When I do this, I get the error: TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'sessions' of undefined in [conferenceData.sessions in ProductListComponent@65:17]

If I assign the child to a variable:

```
this.sessionData = this.conferenceData.sessions;
```

Then bind to the sessionData variable instead, it works as expected.  This is using TypeScript and Angular 2. I suppose this could be a type issue with TypeScript, but I thought by this time it was all JavaScript.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you retrieving the `conferenceData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably, because `this.conferenceData` is not assigned yet, when Angular is rendering your view the first time.

You can easily fix this with the elvis operator:

```js
<div *ngFor="#session of conferenceData?.sessions">{{session.title}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is the **time** to fetch the json data, the component doesn't have the data when the angular renders the view. The **solution** is uses '**elvis**' (**?**) operator to ensure the data is ready:
- 
`<div *ngFor="#session of conferenceData?.sessions">
    {{session.title}}
</div>`

The **second solution** is **hide** the **ngFor** until the `conferenceData`  **is ready**:

`<div *ngIf="conferenceData">
    <div *ngFor="#session of conferenceData.sessions">
        {{session.title}}
    </div>
</div>`